# Seperate Records to share Date Range utilizing a single column of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following records from my table called Disbursements.  What I like to do is break out each record into its separate record set of records based on the Beginning and Ending Service Date utilizing only 1 column of dates.

```
 DisbursementID ServiceProviderID Original CircuitID   Beginning_Service_Date Ending_Service_Date Amount
 -------------- ----------------- -------- ----------- ---------------------- ------------------- -----------
 53562          673               0        1814        2015-12-01             2015-12-31          531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-01             2015-11-30          531
```

My GOAL Result is to look like

```
 DisbursementID ServiceProviderID Original CircuitID   Date Range  Amount
 -------------- ----------------- -------- ----------- ---------- -------
 53562          673               0        1814        2015-12-01 531
 53562          673               0        1814        2015-12-02 531
 53562          673               0        1814        2015-12-03 531
 53562          673               0        1814        2015-12-04 531
 53562          673               0        1814        2015-12-05 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-01 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-02 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-03 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-04 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-05 531
```

Instead my result looks like

```
 DisbursementID ServiceProviderID Original CircuitID   Date Range  Amount
 -------------- ----------------- -------- ----------- ---------- -------
 53562          673               0        1814        2015-12-01 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-01 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-02 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-03 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-04 531
 53563          673               0        1814        2015-11-05 531
```

The following is a piece of code that I found but adapted to my needs.  It almost solves my problem but I cant figure out how to include the block of range dates from my first record.  I know why it does it, but do not know how to properly fix it:

```
 ;With Dates as
 ( 
 Select DisbursementID, ServiceProviderID,Original,CircuitID
 ,Beginning_Service_Date as BeginDate, Ending_Service_Date as EndDate
 ,Amount From Disbursement

 Union All

 Select DisbursementID, ServiceProviderID, Original,CircuitID
 ,DATEADD(day,1,BeginDate) as CalenderDate, EndDate
 ,Amount 
 From Dates
 Where DATEADD(day,1,BeginDate) <= EndDate
 )

 Select DisbursementID, ServiceProviderID,Original,CircuitID
,BeginDate as [Date Range], Amount from Dates
Order By CircuitID
Option (MAXRECURSION 366);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have or can't use a Tally/Calendar Table, another approach would be to use an ad-hoc tally table.

```
Declare @YourTable table (DisbursementID int, ServiceProviderID int, Original int, CircuitID int, Beginning_Service_Date date, Ending_Service_Date date, Amount int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ( 53562,673,0,1814,'2015-12-01','2015-12-31',531)
,( 53563,673,0,1814,'2015-11-01','2015-11-30',531)

;with cte1 as (
                 Select MinDate=min(Beginning_Service_Date)
                       ,MaxDate=max(Ending_Service_Date)
                 From @YourTable )
     ,cte2 as (
                 Select Top (DateDiff(DD,(select MinDate from cte1),(select MaxDate from cte1))+1) 
                        D = DateAdd(DD,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)),(select MinDate from cte1)) 
                  From  master..spt_values A -- ,master..spt_values B  -- If you need more than 6 years
 )
Select A.DisbursementID 
      ,A.ServiceProviderID 
      ,A.Original 
      ,A.CircuitID 
      ,[Date Range] = B.D
      ,A.Amount
 From  @YourTable A
 Join cte2 B on B.D between A.Beginning_Service_Date and A.Ending_Service_Date
```

Comment: Thank you.  I dont have a TALLY/CALENDAR table and I have no idea how the CROSS APPLY works, but will look into it now.

Comment: Oh I like your edited Another Option solution.  My ETL process that utilizes SQL code ran into problems using your first solution, but your EDITED Solution, It took it a lot better.

Comment: @CharlesBernardes Odd that you had an issue with the first.  I got the same results with both.   Keep the CROSS APPLY in your back-pocket.  They are useful... think of them as a sub-routine

Comment: When I ran it in SSMS against 55,000 records, it eventually gave me an error message
Msg 127, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
A TOP N or FETCH rowcount value may not be negative.

Comment: I thought your solution was working till I ran a few tests.  It seems not all records are not all being returned.  Is their a way I can send you a personal e-mail?  Otherwise, I am not sure how I can give you a copy of all the records from my table to show you what it is not returning.  I have over 50,000 records in my table.  I dont understand your code enough to find out why it is acting in such a manner.

Comment: @CharlesBernardes Run the Query in cte1 ... the min/max dates.  Is this greater than 6 years?

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive cte is one of the worst ways to generate a range of dates. The answer by **John Cappelletti** is [**much better**](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) for generating the date range on demand than using a recursive cte.

If you are going to be using it across 55,000+ rows, and you will be running this sort of operation more than once, you would be better off just creating a `Dates` or `Calendar` table.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table, and you could use it like so:

```
/* dates table */ 
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
               cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date 
  on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

And use the `Dates` table like so:

```
select 
    t.DisbursementID
  , t.ServiceProviderID
  , t.Original
  , t.CircuitID
  , d.[date]
  , t.Amount
from t
  inner join dates d
    --on d.date >= t.Beginning_Service_Date
   --and d.date <= t.Ending_Service_Date
  /* if you want to have the date range work when 
      Beginning_Service_Date and Ending_Service_Date are backwards
      you could use between */
    on d.date between t.Beginning_Service_Date
                  and t.Ending_Service_Date
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WNMJW41879

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

Comment: you are correct that it is a huge performance issue.  I do notice that.  He (John) did ask if I had a Calendar type of table and I didnt. So he didnt provide his initial answers based on that.  Plus, I didnt know how to create one to use it properly against my code I provided.  
But you did and gave me another alternate way of looking at this.  I appreciate this a lot.

Comment: @CharlesBernardes  John's answer is a good one (I upvoted it as well), but the comment about using it over 55,000 rows was a good enough reason for me to offer this alternative.

Comment: I gave john the points for the answer, since he did give me a solution that did work according to my initial post.   Since you followed it up with a better alternative, I wish I could give you credit to an answer too.  I hope you are not offended.  I did give you an upvote too.

Comment: @CharlesBernardes Not at all, as I said before John's answer is a good one. An upvote is plenty if you found my answer worthy of consideration as an alternative.